# Web Application which requires keyboard input even without browser focus

Tags: c#, web-applications, activex, hook, keyboard-hook

I am creating a website application which requires keyboard input, specifically without browser focus.

Without giving too much away about my great application idea (=P), I want to respond (even to just a  single) keyboard key press, with the understanding that the browser will not have focus.

I have been doing a great deal of studying on this front, and I have found much help with keyboard 'hooks', so that no matter which application has focus, I can react to key inputs (the ones I have been playing with are in vc#). And these work, for executables, but I am not sure how to get them into the browser with my web application.

What my question is: Can I use ActiveX (or anything of that ilk - wpf?) to get access to keyboard input regardless of the browser having focus or not.

Thanks so very much for your time, I would love to learn if this type of thing is even possible, before wasting my time learning how to create and use ActiveX (just to learn that it is not).

Comment: Sounds like you want to stick a keylogger on a webpage. Without giving too much away about your great application idea (=P) why are you bothering? It sounds like a security hole big enough to drive fire-trucks through.

Comment: @Vandenberg I think that is why there are a half dozen warnings, pop-ups, and dialog boxes warning you to make sure you trust that given organization... it is in no way a stealthy operation for a key-logger. As far as me bothering - I feel that a single 'hot-key' which can be activated would very much increase the users experience. If what I ask is impossible, I will offer a download-able version, which will allow for the keyboard hooks.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that most browsers are not capable of a 'level of trust' high enough to allow this sort of thing.

Comment: @Barber I would think that you are right, but I did want to hear if anyone knew for sure either way.

Answer (score 0):

The best (possibly only) way to do this would probably be to launch a seperate, medium integrity process (you have to register that properly when you install the control or it won't let you launch it) and have the process run when you need your access.  Then you can use interprocess communication to report to the control when something happens that it should know about, possibly firing an event to javascript.

Be very careful how you use this, of course, because if done improperly it could cause a major security hole which would tend to make everyone hate you (most developers consider this a bad thing).  For the interprocess communication you could use boost IPC stuff or named pipes.